Regarding Optaplanner/tiimefold.ai
I have a use case where I want to assign a salesperson to a list of appointments. Now, these salespeople have to travel from one point to another to reach the appointment location. I am using Optaplanner to schedule a list of salespersons for a bunch of appointments.
step1: it schedule all the tasks to the sp and give some score i,e -100hard/0medium/-1000soft
step2: then it run and try to give the best solution where the score is best but if anyhow for some task constraints is alwasy broken in my case due to overcapacity and my score is -2hard/0medium/0soft
but for those 2 task i'm getting assigned sp but i dont want as constraits is broken
how can i achieve it?
I added a dummy techncian and assigned all the task to him where im not able to find right techncian but its not a correct aproach

In case your domain design uses the planning list variable, there is no need for introducing "dummy technician". The planning list variable supports unassigned values.
The second part is introducing a new constraint that penalizes for every unassigned appointment on the medium score level.
See the Overconstrained planning for more details.
